# How to detect if a stored procedure already exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have to write a deployment script which will work if a stored procedure exists or does not exist.   i.e. if it exists, then I need to alter it, otherwise create it.

How can I do this in the sql.

I am using SQL Server 2005

Comment: Related post - [How to check if a stored procedure exists before creating it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2072086/465053)

Answer (score 166):

If you DROP and CREATE the procedure, you will loose the security settings.  This might annoy your DBA or break your application altogether.

What I do is create a trivial stored procedure if it doesn't exist yet.  After that, you can ALTER the stored procedure to your liking.

```
IF object_id('YourSp') IS NULL
    EXEC ('create procedure dbo.YourSp as select 1')
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.YourSp
AS
...
```

This way, security settings, comments and other meta deta will survive the deployment.

Comment: At least if you drop it you know you have to re-add the permissions. If you ran this sql you would not know whether the sproc had the correct permissions or not as you wouldn't know if you had created it or altered it.

Comment: @Liazy the simple solution there is to add code in the `if object_id('YourSp') is null BEGIN ... END` to add the proper permissions after creating the stored procedure.

Comment: think the other answer is a little more complete as it only pulls the object id for stored procedures. not common to have the same name for different types but it could happen

Answer (score 157):

The cleanest way is to test for it's existence, drop it if it exists, and then recreate it.  You can't embed a "create proc" statement inside an IF statement.  This should do nicely:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('MySproc', 'P') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROC MySproc
GO

CREATE PROC MySproc
AS
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

Comment: This will work, but it removes any security changes applied to the stored procedure.

Comment: Security changes should be part of scripts as well. That way, it will get properly documented. This is the right approach.

Comment: @EnderWiggin Except if the security implementation is not know at design time... What if the developer does not know which users need execute rights?

Comment: @AdriaanDavel l that's what DBAs are for, and getting DBAs to talk to developers is called management. If developers and DBAs can't work together there's a problem with the company. Besides, properly implemented systems don't rely on user privilege to touch a database, that's what service accounts are for, and service level security should be applicable database-wide, this way DBAs don't have to spend time and money tweaking security on individual sprocs.

Comment: @ShaunWilson How do you manage DBAs to talk to developers if its a commercial product? Should developers field calls from all customers?

Comment: I wouldn't have developers dropping/recreating sprocs that belonged to a commercial product. Come to think about it, I wouldn't have DBAs doing that either. 
I see what you're getting at, though, i.e. "what if DBAs need to tweak security on a sproc post-deployment for a commerical product". 
I'll reiterate that properly implemented systems don't rely on user privileges and that service-level security should be applied database-wide.
I've worked with DBAs that will install to a demo/scratch system and then do a schema compare to ensure an upgrade is safe, IMO this is what they're hired to do.

Answer (score 33):

If you are dealing only with stored procedures, the easiest thing to do is to probably drop the proc, then recreate it.  You can generate all of the code to do this using the Generate Scripts wizard in SQL Server.

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[YourSproc]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[YourSproc]

CREATE PROCEDURE YourSproc...
```

Answer (score 32):

From `SQL Server 2016 CTP3` you can use new *DIE*  statements instead of big `IF` wrappers

Syntax:

> DROP { PROC | PROCEDURE } [ IF EXISTS ] { [ schema_name. ] procedure }
>   [ ,...n ]

Query:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_name
```

More info [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174969.aspx)

Answer (score 13):

```
if not exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[xxx]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
BEGIN
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.xxx
```

where `xxx` is the proc name

Answer (score 7):

You can write a query as follows:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('ProcedureName','P') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROC ProcedureName
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureName]
...your query here....
```

To be more specific on the above syntax:
**OBJECT_ID** is a unique id number for an object within the database, this is used internally by SQL Server. Since we are passing **ProcedureName** followed by you object type **P** which tells the SQL Server that you should find the object called **ProcedureName** which is of type **procedure i.e., P**

This query will find the procedure and if it is available it will drop it and create new one.

For detailed information about OBJECT_ID and Object types please visit : **[SYS.Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what has already been said I also like to add a different approach and advocate the use of differential script deployment strategy. [Instead of making a stateful script that always checks the current state and acts based on that state, deploy via a series of stateless scripts that upgrade from well known versions](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/). I have used this strategy and it pays off big time as my deployment scripts are now all 'IF' free.

Comment: Interesting! In the five years since you posted this answer, have then been further developments in your database version control methods?

Answer (score 3):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('SPNAME') IS NULL
     -- Does Not Exists
ELSE
     -- Exists
```

Answer (score 0):

A better option might be to use a tool like Red-Gate SQL Compare or SQL Examiner to automatically compare the differences and generate a migration script.

Answer (score 0):

I have a stored proc that allows the customer to extend validation, if it exists I do not want to change it, if it doesn't I want to create it, the best way I have found:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('ValidateRequestPost') IS NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE ValidateRequestPost 
    @RequestNo VARCHAR(30),
    @ErrorStates VARCHAR(255) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @ErrorStates = @ErrorStates
END')
END
```

Comment: I didn't provide the down-vote, but, at a guess, I would say that it was down-voted because this solution introduces new complications with escaping quote characters within the body of the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will check whether the stored procedure already exists or not.

If it exists it will alter, if it doesn't exist it will create a new stored procedure for you:

```
//syntax for Create and Alter Proc 
DECLARE @Create NVARCHAR(200) = 'Create PROCEDURE sp_cp_test'; 
DECLARE @Alter NVARCHAR(200) ='Alter PROCEDURE sp_cp_test'; 
//Actual Procedure 
DECLARE @Proc NVARCHAR(200)= ' AS BEGIN select ''sh'' END'; 
//Checking For Sp
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM   sysobjects 
           WHERE  id = Object_id('[dbo].[sp_cp_test]') 
                  AND Objectproperty(id, 'IsProcedure') = 1 
                  AND xtype = 'p' 
                  AND NAME = 'sp_cp_test') 
  BEGIN 
      SET @Proc=@Alter + @Proc 

      EXEC (@proc) 
  END 
ELSE 
  BEGIN 
      SET @Proc=@Create + @Proc 

      EXEC (@proc) 
  END 

go
```