# How do I create a Stored Procedure if it doesn't exist in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have tried this:

```
if object_id('a_proc22') is not null
CREATE PROCEDURE a_proc22 AS SELECT 1
go
```

but it gives me a syntax error.

But this seemed to compile:

```
if object_id('a_proc22') is not null
EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE a_proc22 AS SELECT 1')
go
```

Why is the first one incorrect?

Comment: I don't know SQL-Server but I doubt that it compiles if you have a syntax error.

Comment: Is this the same problem as answered here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072086/t-sql-check-if-a-procedure-exists-before-creating-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937908/how-to-detect-if-a-stored-procedure-already-exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the error is something like "CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE must be the first statement in a query", so, well, that means that `CREATE PROCEDURE` must be the **first** statement in a query. If you wrapped it up on an `EXEC`, then when its executed, it is the first statement on that query, so that's why it works.

Comment: Came here to say this. Sayeth BOL: "The CREATE PROCEDURE statement cannot be combined with other Transact-SQL statements in a single batch." So it must be the first *and last* statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[a_proc22]')
           AND TYPE IN (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[a_proc22];
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[a_proc22]
AS
BEGIN 

-- Code here

END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if object_id('a_proc22') is not null
drop procedure a_proc22 
go
create procedure a_proc22 
AS 
SELECT 1
```

The GO is the important thing here after the drop, you can't have create first, some SQL validation I guess for security purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement is giving error because after if condition you can not place a create/alter procedure statement.
Try this

```
if Exists(select * from sys.procedures  -- if exists then drop it
    where name = 'a_proc22')
    Drop procedure a_proc22
    GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE a_proc22 -- create the new procedure
    AS
    SELECT 1
    go
```

Answer (score -1):

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[a_proc22]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[a_proc22]
--and create here... Or you can remove the drop and create with if not exists
GO
```

Comment: The question is why did the first SQL statement fail.

Comment: The heading is "How do I create a Stored Procedure if it doesn't exist in TSQL". I should have said that create should be the first in a query batch to answer his question. But I think the answer is correct for the heading.