# How to add "IF NOT EXISTS" to create trigger statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, triggers

I am using sql server 2008 R2.  More specifically, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor).  I am new to sql server and procedures/triggers.  I have the following code to create a trigger (it works):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Insert_WithdrawalCodes] 
   ON  [dbo].[PupilWithdrawalReason] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        UPDATE [dbo].[PupilWithdrawalReason] SET DateCreated=dbo.SYSTEMTIME() 
        WHERE WithdrawalCodeID IN (SELECT WithdrawalCodeID FROM inserted)
END
```

How do I conditionally create only if the trigger does not yet exist?  What am I doing wrong here?  StackOverflow has good examples of `IF NOT EXISTS`, but I can't get this to work in conjunction with a `CREATE`.  Here is one of my failed efforts:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'TR' AND name = 'Insert_WithdrawalCodes')
   exec('CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Insert_WithdrawalCodes] ON  [dbo].[PupilWithdrawalReason] AFTER INSERT AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; UPDATE [dbo].[PupilWithdrawalReason] SET DateCreated=dbo.SYSTEMTIME() WHERE WithdrawalCodeID IN (SELECT WithdrawalCodeID FROM inserted) END')
GO
```

Comment: I updated my failed example.  Why doesn't the "exec" code work?  Is my syntax wrong in the create?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TRIGGERNAME]'))
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIGGERNAME]
go
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TABLENAME]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
BEGIN
CREATE   TRIGGER [dbo].[TRIGGERNAME] ON [dbo].[TABLENAME] FOR INSERT, UPDATE 

AS ...

END
```

Based on your updated question... try this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from sys.objects where type = 'TR' and name = 'Insert_WithdrawalCodes')
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Insert_WithdrawalCodes] 
   ON  [dbo].[PupilWithdrawalReason] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        UPDATE [dbo].[PupilWithdrawalReason] SET DateCreated=dbo.SYSTEMTIME() 
        WHERE WithdrawalCodeID IN (SELECT WithdrawalCodeID FROM inserted)
END


 '
```

Comment: I really do want to use "if not exists".  This question has some answers which explain why "if not exists" is better.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937908/how-to-detect-if-a-stored-procedure-already-exists.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.  I tried that code and got this: Error 330 SQL03070: This statement is not recognized in this context.

Comment: What version of SQL are you in?

Comment: I added the version to my original question.

Comment: Your latest code throws no errors for me.  What error do you get?

Comment: It isn't working when I deploy the database project through visual studio.  However, in sql management server this works, so I'm marking as accepted.  Thanks!

Comment: This is the error: "Error 330 SQL03070: This statement is not recognized in this context."

Comment: If your trigger definition contains literal strings (delimited by single quotes) this will break your nvarchar value being supplied to <at>statement. To circumvent this, after your IF statement I added BEGIN and END clauses. Within those I have declare <at>statement nvarchar(max); set <at>statement = N'create trigger .... ' + nchar(39) + N'Your literal string value within the trigger definition, in here' + nchar(39) + N' .... remainder of trigger definition;' EXEC dbo.sp_executesql <at>statement; You'll need this funky nchar stuff for each literal string in your trigger definition.

Answer (score 14):

The best way is to check for objects and drop them if they exist before you create them.

Rather then not creating it at all if it exists, I would approach it the other way, drop it if exists and then create.

Normally in long lenghty scripts if you want to update the definition of a trigger you would just simply add this at the end of that script and your trigger definition will be updated.

So the approach should be `create the object but drop it if it already exists` rather then `dont create it at all if it already exists`

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('[Insert_WithdrawalCodes] ', 'TR') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TRIGGER [Insert_WithdrawalCodes];
GO

CREATE TRIGGER .......
```

Comment: I really do want to use "if not exists".  This question has some answers which explain why "if not exists" is better.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937908/how-to-detect-if-a-stored-procedure-already-exists.

Comment: For those looking for an explanation: `if not exists` allows to verify the object is indeed a trigger.

Comment: You need to drop the [ and ] from your argument to OBJECT_ID.

Answer (score 13):

Certain statements like CREATE TRIGGER needs to be the first in a batch (as in, group of statements separated by GO ).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175502.aspx

Alternatively you could do this

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM    sys.objects
            WHERE   type = 'TR'
                    AND name = 'Insert_WithdrawalCodes' ) 
BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE TRIGGER Insert_WithdrawalCodes ON ...');
END;
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work.  I'm going to update my question with the code which didn't work - would be great if you can spot why it isn't working.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937908/how-to-detect-if-a-stored-procedure-already-exists.

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon after EXEC(). Try this EXEC('CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Insert_WithdrawalCodes] ON  [dbo].[PupilWithdrawalReason] AFTER INSERT AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; UPDATE [dbo].[PupilWithdrawalReason] SET DateCreated=dbo.SYSTEMTIME() WHERE WithdrawalCodeID IN (SELECT WithdrawalCodeID FROM inserted) END');

Comment: Thank you for noticing that!

Comment: Note that for DDL triggers you must query sys.server_triggers and not sys.triggers.  It took me a while to figure that out.

Answer (score 7):

As other answers above not mentioned an important point I wrote this answer:

- When we want to find a trigger or another object in `sys.objects` table, it is better to check accurately (with schema or `object_id`, etc) in where clause to avoid same name invalid results.
  Consider when another trigger with the same name already exists in another schema... 
  Therefore, because the `sys.object` table contains an `schema_id` column, we can use it in addition to `name` and `type` columns to query more accurately as I provided as example below.
- As Microsoft docs mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) under "Trigger Limitations":

> CREATE TRIGGER must be the first statement in the batch and can apply
>   to only one table.

therefore we use [EXECUTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to overcome this limitation:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from sys.objects where schema_id=SCHEMA_ID('dbo') AND type='TR' and name='Insert_WithdrawalCodes')
BEGIN
   EXECUTE ('CREATE TRIGGER [Insert_WithdrawalCodes] ON [dbo].[PupilWithdrawalReason]
   AFTER INSERT
   AS 
   BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      ...
   END');
END
```

Comment: This is underrated.