# T-SQL Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I created instead of trigger like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ReadOnlyEvent ON 
TableName INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS BEGIN 
RAISERROR('Tables are read only.', 16, 1 ) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION END;
```

And that code works fine. But when i combine this with 'IF' i got an error:

```
 IF OBJECT_ID ('ReadOnlyEvent', 'TR') IS NULL 
    CREATE TRIGGER ReadOnlyEvent ON
 TableName INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS BEGIN 
 RAISERROR('Tables are read only.', 16, 1 ) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION END;
```

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRIGGER'.

I also tryed IF with BEGIN END:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('ReadOnlyEvent', 'TR') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TRIGGER ReadOnlyEvent ON
    TableName INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS BEGIN 
    RAISERROR('Tables are read only.', 16, 1 ) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION END;
END;
```

Why i got this error? :-)

Comment: should help u...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28225329/how-to-add-if-not-exists-to-create-trigger-statement

Comment: And note, particularly, that `CREATE TRIGGER` has to be the first statement in a batch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard construction

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('ReadOnlyEvent', 'TR') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TRIGGER dbo.ReadOnlyEvent
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.ReadOnlyEvent ON
  TableName INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS BEGIN 
RAISERROR('Tables are read only.', 16, 1 ) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION END;
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This one

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  *  FROM    sys.objects WHERE   type = 'TR'
                    AND name = 'ReadOnlyEvent' ) 

BEGIN
    EXEC ('CREATE TRIGGER ReadOnlyEvent ON
    TableName INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS BEGIN 
    RAISERROR('Tables are read only.', 16, 1 ) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION END');
END;
```

Comment: @Yogesh Sharma
Incorrect syntax near 'Tables'.

But is so close to solve. When i remove  RAISEERROR statment it's fine. Problem with escaping(?) ' characters that close the exec command on wrong ' character.
Working code but without raiseerror

`code`
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.objects
      WHERE type = 'TR'
               AND name = 'CRMTelefonRekorduKampaniiReadOnlyEvent' ) 
  BEGIN
      EXEC ('CREATE TRIGGER ReadOnlyEvent ON CRMTelefonRekorduKampanii INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS BEGIN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION END');
END;`code'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
BEGIN 
    IF OBJECT_ID ('ReadOnlyEvent', 'TR') IS NULL 
        BEGIN
            CREATE TRIGGER ReadOnlyEvent ON
            TableName INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS BEGIN 
            RAISERROR('Tables are read only.', 16, 1 ) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION END;
        END 
END
```